# getting an input with specific format in c

Tags: c, readfile

I am trying to read a file in C language!

The format of the file is this:
(IP address,IP address,cost)
for example:

```
(127.0.0.1,128.1.11.12,12)
(127.0.1.2,128.0.1.12,12)
(127.0.3.4,128.4.0.12,12)
```

and etc

I have the following code but unfortunately this code is not working! The problem is all of my line is going into the dest_ip variable and the rest of the variables are going to be null for each line!

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks

```
//open the fp and etc
char * source_ip;
char * dest_ip;
int cost;
int counter = my_ips_size;
printf("I am about to read\n");
while (fscanf(fp,"(%s,%s,%d)",dest_ip,source_ip,&cost) != EOF) { //do what ever
```

Comment: Are you not forgetting about the comma's in the input line?

Comment: Sorry my bad! Right now the code should look fine!

Comment: user3121023: your code is getting the dest_ip, but it is still null for the source_ip and cost!

Comment: That was the problem Thanks for the respond!!! Can you please post your solution so I can choose as an answer! Again Thanks

Comment: Consider `char dest_ip[16]; char source_ip[16]; if(fscanf(fp," (%15[0-9.],%15[0-9.],%d)",dest_ip,source_ip,&cost)== 3) ...`.  This limits input to 15 `char` and does not scan in an unusual `'\0'` like `"%[^,]"` does.

Comment: user3121023: I did this and it is working!
source_ip = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*));
dest_ip = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char*));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Chux solution in the comment and it is working perfect!!!!!

Consider char dest_ip[16]; char source_ip[16]; if(fscanf(fp," (%15[0-9.],%15[0-9.],%d)",dest_ip,source_ip,&cost)== 3) .... This limits input to 15 char and does not scan in an unusual '\0' like "%[^,]" does